# How to load redis config file on `redis-server`?

Tags: redis

I have installed redis on Mac OS throw brew. I can start the default by running the command `redis-server`. But I get an error when start the server by running: `redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`:

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 194
>>> 'always-show-logo yes'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

I didn't change anything on the conf file and if I remove the line 194 then I will get another line error. Is there anything wrong I did? What is the correct way to launch redis server with a configuration file?

I have checked that the file `/usr/local/etc/redis.conf` exists on the system and my redis server version is:

```
$ redis-server --version
Redis server v=3.2.0 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=85fa89b1ccb3084c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its simple , you can start the redis server using following cmd

```
# run in background 
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf(path to redis config) &
```

it worked for me.

Error is simple ur using wrong config file, whatever the config mentioned is redis version 4.0 , but you are running with 3.2

i guess u might have 2 version of redis installed and u can check which version redis-server is calling using

```
which redis-server
```

And try search different config file if any using

```
 locate redis.conf
```

One option is to uninstall redis-server or update redis-server

For Update following should work

```
brew upgrade redis
```

after that you can start using

```
redis-server &
```

Answer (score 1):

Brew will install the newest version of redis(4.0.6 for now), if you don't config other things. So I'm not sure you installed version 3.2.0 on purpose or by mistake(maybe downloaded manually earlier).

And  `always-show-logo` config  is not supported by 3.2.0.

So, you can remove all old versions of redis on your machine, and run the brew install again, or you can find a redis.conf fit for 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

1, Check the existence of /usr/local/etc/redis.conf.
2, If step1 passed, check the version of redis version, configuration always-show-logo does not exists in redis 3.2 and then versions previous to 3.2.

Comment: I have added these two checks on my post

Comment: You should remove always-show-logo from your redis.conf，otherwise redis server will never get started.